# updateOrCreate does not work in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to update or create a model. It's not working at all.

Here is my code:

```php
foreach ($ProfileRequest as $fieldname => $value){
    ProfileRequest::updateOrCreate(['sm_id' => $uid, 'field_name' => $fieldname],
        [
            'sm_id' => $uid,
            'field_name' => $fieldname,
            'value' => $value
        ]);
    }
```

This is working for insertion:

```php
 foreach ($ProfileRequest as $fieldname => $value) {
     $req = new ProfileRequest;
     $req->chef_id = $uid;
     $req->field_name = $fieldname;
     $req->value = $value;
     $req->save();
 }
```

Comment: Please describe what exactly doesn't work, what exactly you're doing and what error do you get.

Comment: this code does not creating or updating the same

Comment: while $req = new ProfileRequest;
            $req->chef_id = $uid;
            $req->field_name = $fieldname;
            $req->value = $value;
            $req->save(); is working

Answer (score 34):

You need to specify the fillable fields in your model since you are dealing with Mass Updates. Put this at your model

```
protected $fillable = ['field_name','value'];
```

Comment: I was just running an updateOrCreate() in a Seeder file, it was working perfectly fine in there but not in a controller. It tripped me up a bit, I couldn't understand why, but your answer was the reason. So obvious now.

Comment: This one saved my day, thanks for the answer. For people getting this error "Field 'field_name' doesn't have a default value at..." this answer can be useful

Comment: you're a hero...

Answer (score 4):

Change your code like this

```
foreach ($ProfileRequest as $fieldname => $value){
    ProfileRequest::updateOrCreate(
        [
            'sm_id' => $uid
        ], 
        [
            'field_name' => $fieldname,
            'value' => $value
        ]
    );
}
```

Avoid repeating the fields. If somehow, my code doesn't work for you, please go check the function definition for yourself here: https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_updateOrCreate

Answer (score -2):

This works

```
foreach ($ProfileRequest as $fieldname => $value){
    ProfileRequest::firstOrNew(array('sm_id' => $uid, 'field_name' => $fieldname));
            $chefReq->sm_id = $uid;
            $chefReq->field_name = $fieldname;
            $chefReq->value = $value;
            $chefReq->save();
}
```